# To compare two arrays while considering duplicate value

Tags: php

i have two arrays

```
$array1 = array(1, 2,  2, 3);
$array2 = array( 1, 2,  3,4);
```

and when did :

```
var_dump(array_diff($array1, $array2));
```

getting :

```
array(0){}
```

as  output , but i am looking for :

```
array(1){[2]=>2}
```

can someone please let me know how to do it

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you expecting `array(2)`? `2` is found in both arrays, hence it won't be found in the difference. That's it.

Comment: `arary_diff` returns an array containing all entries from `array1` that are **not** present in any other arrays.

Comment: yeah, array_diff returns an array containing all entries from array1 that are not present in any other arrays but i need to check duplicate values too, and array_diff didn't fulfill that requirement that's why looking for some alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 3, 5);
$diff = array_filter($array1, 
  function ($val) use (&$array2) { 
    $key = array_search($val, $array2);
    if ( $key === false ) return true;
    unset($array2[$key]);
    return false;
  }
);
print_r($diff);
// Array ( [2] => 2 [6] => 5 [7] => 7 )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count number of duplicate element from same array as well as from multiple arrays, please use below code,

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(1,2,2,3,7);
    $array2 = array(1,2,3,4);
    $diff_array = array();

    $diff_array1 = array_count_values($array1);
    $diff_array2 = array_count_values($array2);

    $a = array_keys($diff_array1);
    $b = array_keys($diff_array2);

    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
    {
        if($a[$i] == $b[$i])
        {
            $x = $a[$i];
            $y = $b[$i];
            $diff_array1[$x] += $diff_array2[$y];
        }
    } 
    $diff_array1=array_diff($diff_array1, array('1'));
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($diff_array1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the desired result:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2,  2, 3);
$array2 = array( 1, 2,  3,4);

$countArray1 = array_count_values($array1);
$countArray2 = array_count_values($array2);

foreach($countArray1 as $value=>$count) {
    if($count > 1) $dupArray[] = $value;
}

foreach($countArray2 as $value=>$count) {
    if($count > 1) $dupArray[] = $value;
}

print_r($dupArray);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
```

**Explanation**

Using `array_count_values` will count all the values of an array, which would look like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
)

Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
)
```

We then iterate through each `array_count_values` to locate values that occur more than once. This will work when you have more than one set of duplicate values:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2,  2, 3);
$array2 = array( 1, 2,  3, 4, 3);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

Answer (score -1):

While it may be less elegant, the simple way to do this is with a for loop:

```
$diff_array = array();
for ($i = 0; ($i < count($array1)) and ($i < count($array2)); $i++)
{
   if ($array1[$i] !== $array2[$i]) { $diff_array[$i] = $array1[$i]; }
}
```

Comment: What if the arrays are different sizes? This code would return the `3`. The OP is looking for the duplicate values, not the difference between each array.

Comment: The advantage of this method is that you have control over what you do. If the arrays are different sizes you can do for example:
($i < count($array1) and $i < count($array2)); as the stopping condition for the loop.