# Find all anagram words in a text file

Tags: php

So I have a file of words. When a person enters a they should get back all anagrams of that word if any.

Example: enter 'hat' check the file for anything 3 characters with h-a-t

so this where I am at now..

```
    $wordlist=file_get_contents('words.txt');
    $word = $_POST['word'];

    $word_split = str_split($word);

    foreach($wordlist as $line){
       if(strpos($line, $word_split) !== false){
          echo $line;
      }
    }
```

This of course is not working because you cannot use an array as the needle. So I am stuck on how to do it.

Comment: This might be of intereset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045640/how-to-check-if-two-words-are-anagrams-in-java

Comment: The [`count_chars()`](http://php.net/count_chars) function would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment below if there's anything wrong with it (I changed the input to $_GET for easier testing).

```
//Check first if there's any word input
if(isset($_GET['word'])){
    $wordlist = explode("\n", file_get_contents('words.txt'));
    $word = $_GET['word'];
    $word_split = str_split($word);
    //print_r($word_split);
    $word_length = strlen(trim($word));
    foreach($wordlist as $line){

        $line_split = str_split(rtrim($line));
        $line_length = strlen(trim($line));
        //Check if the lengths are equal
        $diff = array_filter($word_split, function ($val) use (&$line_split) { $key = array_search($val, $line_split);if ( $key === false ) return true;unset($line_split[$key]);return false;});

        if($line_length == $word_length && empty($diff)){
            echo $line."\n";
        }
    }
}else{
    die("No word input.");
}
```

**Example**

Input word: `post`

Word database (`word.txt`):

```
post
some
pots
random
spot
words
stop
for
tops
testing
```

Output:

```
post
pots
spot
stop
tops
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is close but it's just checking to see if the words are the same length not if they include the same letters                                                              if I enter blue dog I get beglobed

Comment: What else should it do?

Comment: So if I am searching hat it should find the words with the letters h-a-t

Comment: You said "enter 'hat' check the file for anything 3 characters with h-a-t", I'm checking for same length and characters. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Hmm for some reason when I enter words it's not giving me the proper anagram: apple gives me alala

Comment: May I know what kind of words are you entering?

Comment: I entered apple and I got back alala,palla,papal

Comment: I made some changes (after a lot of search :D). Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13122253/2083292