# Check if arrays have the same values with the same frequencies

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with values, e.g.

```
$parameters = ['G', 'W', 'G'];
```

and now I need to check if another array has these values. `$parameters` can have duplicated values and can be in random order so if I'll check these values are in array

```
$array = ['W', 'G', 'G'];
```

it should return `true` but on check with

```
$array2 = ['W', 'G'];
```

should return `false`

How to best do this? I have idea for create `$array` with count for every letter, next count of every value in `$parameters` and compare it. Is it a good way?

Comment: This sounds really overengineered. Can you explain what exactly it is you need as I feel like there might be a simpler solution for what you're trying to solve.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? What does not work yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To compare two arrays while considering duplicate value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121812/to-compare-two-arrays-while-considering-duplicate-value)

Comment: Does the other array ($array) can have more than the values from $paramaters ?

Comment: @Paul Besides being slower and more complex, the answer you've accepted doesn't work (try with `['A', 'A', 'B']` and `['A', 'B', 'B']` for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, you need to compare two arrays for same content without caring for the order. Check this:

```
if (count(array_diff(array_merge($parameters, $array), array_intersect($parameters, $array))) === 0) { 
    /**... */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good: its algorithmic complexity is `O(n + m)`, and it is really easy to implement using the [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-count-values.php) function and the [equality operator](https://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.array.php):

```
function compareArrayFrequency(array $a, array $b): bool {
    return array_count_values($a) == array_count_values($b);
}
```